# Redmine and Related issues

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

Is there a way to export tickets with the "related issues" status?

As far as I can see, I have no opportunity to export the information on related issues.

Thanks,

Mario

Answer (score 0):

There is no way so far, unless you want to go the database directly. You can use the redmine-java-model on google code if you want to do that in java.